# Rotate a matrix by 90 degrees - in Java

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

I need to write a method that rotates a matrix (of objects) by 90 degrees, both directions.

for example -

```
( 0,0,0) (0,0,0) (0,0,0) (0,0,0)

( 1,1,1) (1,1,1) (1,1,1) (1,1,1)

( 2,2,2) (2,2,2) (2,2,2) (2,2,2)
```

becomes -

```
(2,2,2) (1,1,1) (0,0,0)

(2,2,2) (1,1,1) (0,0,0)

(2,2,2) (1,1,1) (0,0,0)

(2,2,2) (1,1,1) (0,0,0)
```

I can't get over the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error.

This is my work so far -

```
private RGBColor [][] _picture;
private int _row;
private int _col;

public RGBImage(RGBColor[][] pixels)
{
    _picture = new RGBColor [pixels.length][pixels[0].length];
    _row = pixels.length;
    _col = pixels[0].length;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < pixels.length ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < pixels[0].length ; j++)
        {
            _picture[i][j] = pixels[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public double[][] toGrayscaleArray ( )
{
    double [][] copyToGrayscale = new double [_row][_col];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < _row ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < _col ; j++)
            {
               copyToGrayscale [i][j] = _picture[i][j].convertToGrayscale();
            }
        }
        return copyToGrayscale;
}

public void rotateCounterClockwise ( )
{
    RGBImage copy = new RGBImage(_col,_row);
    for(int i=0 ; i < _col ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=_row-1 ; j >0 ; j--)
        {
            copy._picture[i][j]=_picture[j][i];
        }
    } 
    _picture = copy.toRGBColorArray();     
}
```

What should i do?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(int i = amount_columns-1; i>=0; i--) {
    for(int j = amount_rows-1; j>=0; j--) {

         new image[(amount_cols-1)-j][(amount_rows-1)-i] = old image[j][i];
    }

}
```

This bit of code should do the following:

```
amount_colums = 4
amount_row = 3
new image[(amount_cols-1)-j][(amount_rows-1)-i] = old image[j][i]

i=3;j=2 --> new image[4-1-3 = 0][3-1-2 = 0] = old image [2][3];
i=3;j=1 --> new image[4-1-3 = 0][3-1-1 = 1] = old image [1][3];
i=3;j=0 --> new image[4-1-3 = 0][3-1-0 = 2] = old image [0][3];
i=2;j=2 --> new image[4-1-2 = 1][3-1-2 = 0] = old image [2][2];
i=2;j=1 --> new image[4-1-2 = 1][3-1-1 = 1] = old image [1][2];
i=2;j=0 --> new image[4-1-2 = 1][3-1-0 = 2] = old image [0][2];
i=1;j=2 --> new image[4-1-1 = 2][3-1-2 = 0] = old image [2][1];
... and so on.
```

I can't test right now if it doesn't work do tell.

Comment: still getting the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error. i think it's because the cols and rows are not equal...

Comment: I might have swapped the first and second value of i and j in the old image or the new image? Can you try swapping em around? try `new image[(amount_cols-1)-j][(amount_rows-1)-i] = old image[j][i];`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work:

```
    int[][] arr = new int[][]{
        {0,0,0},
        {1,1,1},
        {2,2,2},
        {3,3,3},
        {4,4,4},
    };

    int[][] rotated = new int[arr[0].length][arr.length];
    for (int row = arr.length -1; row >= 0; row--){
        int destCol = arr.length -1 - row;
        int destRow = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++){
            rotated[destRow++][destCol] = arr[row][col];
        }
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < rotated.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < rotated[0].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(rotated[row][col] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Depending in what you need its better use jai API. Or maybe affini transform from java Graphic2D class.

Comment: It works great on equal sides matrix (4X4, 3X3)...but when i use it for 3x4 i still gets "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error...what could cause it? and i can't use external classes =\ part of the assignment. tnx!

Comment: So maybe i'm missing something...when i'm trying to print the output of your code i get the same error as in my program. i'm adding to your code the printing loop, can you please tell me what's wrong with it? tnx :)

Comment: @SaharMalka If comments are not sufficient to express yourself with a code snipet, please, add your code in question into your original question or into an external page and link to it in a comment. The answers should contain only answers and no subsequent questions, in order to benefit the community most.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first reverse/invert then transpose.......
I find this more easy and it is inplace too.

```
public void rotatematrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a) {
    int n=a.size()/2;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        ArrayList<Integer>temp=a.get(i-1);
        a.set(i-1,a.get(a.size()-i));
        a.set(a.size()-i,temp);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<a.get(0).size();j++){
            a.get(i).set(j,a.get(i).get(j)^a.get(j).get(i));
            a.get(j).set(i,a.get(i).get(j)^a.get(j).get(i));
            a.get(i).set(j,a.get(i).get(j)^a.get(j).get(i));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rotate90
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the row ");
        byte row=sc.nextByte();
        System.out.println("enter the column");
        byte column=sc.nextByte();
        int arr[][]=new int[row][column];
        // enterMatrixData(scan, matrix, matrixRow, matrixCol);
        System.out.println("row entered is: "+row+",\ncolumn entered is: "+column);
        System.out.println("now enter the maitix data");
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
                 {
                    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    {
                    arr[j][i]=sc.nextInt();

                    }

                 }

                 for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
                 {
                    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    {

                    System.out.print(arr[j][i]+"\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                 }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("After 90* rotation");

        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)   // logic for clock-wise 90* rotation 
                 {
                    for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
                    {
                     System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to help future readers to understand why your answer solves the issue. Thanks!